# Black screen after selecting "Try ubuntu first" on Asus Q526FA

Tags: asus

When booting Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time on my new Asus Q526FA, I get a black screen when selecting either "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu first". I have not been able to get past this. Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from Asus? And if SSD, updated firmware for SSD? Does it just have Intel video as that should just work.

Comment: I have not updated any firmware and yes it is all intel.